# How to send details to users registered to admin as an email in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a very specific usecase where I want to send an email to the admin of the site whenever a new user is registered . This email is not a welcome email to user but an email to admin which contains details  of new registered user so that I can contact my users later without having to referring to database .

Can I achieve this in wordpress . Thankyou. I am new to wordpress .

Answer (score 0):

In wp-includes/pluggable.php there is a function "wp_new_user_notification" which handles the new registration emails that are being sent to user. Prior to 4.3 it also had an option to send a copy to admin which is deprecated now. In that part of code just take code of wp_email from user block and change the "to" parameters for admin.

It will keep sending it to users and will also send a copy to admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WP action hook ‘user_register’ which fires right after a new user has registered and passes the id of the new user to the callback function.

```
add_action( 'user_register',    'inform_admin');

 function inform_admin ($user_id) {
    $user = get_userdata($user_id);
     //$user is now an object containing details of the user.  e.g. $user->first_name @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_userdata/ for more details
     
    $email_context = ““;
    $subject = ““;
    
    // get the admin email
    $admin_email = get_options('admin_email');

    // send the email
    wp_mail( $admin_email, $subject, $email_context);
}
```